# Upload and fetch MySQL polygons to Python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, shapely

I have to store some polygons in a MySQL database.
I insert a polygon into the database using a query from the MySQL manual

```
SET @g = 'POLYGON((0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0),(5 5,7 5,7 7,5 7, 5 5))';
INSERT INTO geom VALUES (111, ST_GeomFromText(@g));
```

The columns of the table are `id` and `polygon`, the type of the latter column is `POLYGON`, but I have the same issue if it is set to `GEOMETRY`.
Then I fetch the polygon from the database (using *sqlalchemy*) and the result will be bytes.
So I try to convert it into Shapely

```
from shapely import wkb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

my_engine = ... # sqlalchemy engine connecting to the database
df = pd.readsql('SELECT polygon FROM geom WHERE id = 111;', my_engine)
p = df.polygon[0]
wkb.loads(p)
>>> <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7f1896b01b38>
```

I get a point not a polygon. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any of the [geometry format conversion functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html) you're selecting the internal geometry format used by MySQL. The reason why you get a `Point` is that this internal format for your polygon begins with:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...'
```

Interpreted as [WKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) it is:

- `00`: Big endian
- `00 00 00 01`: POINT (2D)
- `03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00`: X-coordinate
- `05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`: Y-coordinate

The solution is to use a suitable conversion function in your query:

```
df = pd.read_sql("""
    SELECT ST_AsWKB(polygon) AS polygon
    FROM geom
    WHERE id = 111;""", my_engine)
```